# Express 4.0 request data received format

Tags: node.js, express, express-4

I'm using express 4.0+ and this is my code

```
var express = require('express');
app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.listen(SERVER_LISTEN_PORT_TWO);

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

On the frontend side, I am sending:

JSON.stringify( {"test":"message"} );

The req.body data printed on the backend side is:

```
{
  {"test":"message"} : ''
}
```

I was using just nodejs' createServer function beforehand and the request data would come in as

```
{"test":"message"}
```

My question is, does express automatically json-encodes/stringifies the incoming data ( it seems like it ) and  how would I be able to disable that? I know I can just not encode the data that I sending from the front-end but I'm not certain why I should change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not sending the correct `Content-Type` in your request. If you are sending a JSON payload, the `Content-Type` needs to be `application/json` and not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: in nodejs' createServer func, I would not receive any data if I set the headers telling it it will be JSON AND json-encoding the message. Now in express, if I don't set the content header to JSON,   is it json-encoding the data automatically? I set the application content to json and it seems to receive the content fine, I just find there is a discrepancy in format settings. After I finish my work, I will post a whole overview.

Comment: It depends on what you are using to send the request in order to know how to change the `Content-Type` appropriately. Perhaps you can include that in your original question.

Comment: I certainly will in a bit. And a quick question if you don't mind, I am right now setting the headers to JSON and also stringifying the message on the front end, and when I receive it in express, it seems that I dont need to JSON.parse the received data; does express parse it automatically with the settings I have up there ^^^

Comment: Yes, that is what `bodyParser.json()` does.